# how to manage two keys in JKS

Tags: java

I have two server

```
1. Tomcat as Application Server
2. Openfire as Chat Server
```

and now i need to manage the traffic by SSL/TSL (https protocol) on both servers. that's why i have created a keystore file and self-signed certificate for both server as :

alias tomcat for Tomcat (app server)

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

and alias openfire for Openfire (xmpp server)

```
keytool -genkey -alias openfire -keyalg RSA
```

both alias have their own unique password and Keystore file has password same as tomcat.

but when i restart tomcat server i am getting error as

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
    at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:328)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:138)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:804)
```

this error came when i added another alias as openfire in keystore file.
and after removing alias by `keytool -delete -alias openfire` tomcat restarts properly and does not cause any error.

here i am unable recognize that how to manage two keys in Keystore ?

Comment: Unrelated question: those keys do no seem to be signed at all. Not even self-signed. What purpose could they possibly serve? Surely you would want to generate some sort of "KumarCA" and sign both keys with this CA? The current approach seems to somewhat go against the point of x.509...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple keys in the keystore, by default Tomcat will simply attempt to read the first one found.

You need to use the `keyAlias` parameter on the `<Connector>` in the `server.xml` to override this behaviour. From [the documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_BIO,_NIO_and_NIO2):

> The alias used for the server key and certificate in the keystore. If not specified, the first key read from the keystore will be used. The order in which keys are read from the keystore is implementation dependent. It may not be the case that keys are read from the keystore in the same order as they were added. If more than one key is present in the keystore it is strongly recommended that a keyAlias is configured to ensure that the correct key is used.